# overwriting a file in java using FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter

I have to accomplish a task of writing a set of data to file, use it, then overwrite it with new data. Thus overwrite of the file takes place repeatedly.I know i can accomplish the above by creating FileWriter object each time with the option to overwrite like below

```
     FileWriter object = new FileWriter("fileName", false)
```

and close it to write to the file.

If i am supposed to overwrite the file n number of times , according to the above method i need to create n number of FileWriter objects. Is there any efficient way to overwrite a file repeatedly by only creating a single FileWriter object?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is actually causing a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: Why can't you store the data in a temporary buffer and replace the contents whenever needed and write it at the completion?

Comment: @JonSkeet: No evidence but creating large number of objects generally is seen as a overhead in java right!

Comment: @ManuViswam: ya i thought about it and i might adopt it. But if i go with the above way, can't it be done without creating FileWriter for each write?

Comment: @aarish: You're writing to the file system. Do you really think object creation is going to be the bottleneck? It's like planning a trip to Mars but worrying about the cost of snacks in the NASA cafeteria. Don't *guess* about performance - *measure* it.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The analogy does convey the point!:D I have measured performances in the past by measuring the time taken using sysout statements, i know it is crude and not the right way. I have heard of profilers in performance measurement. So what technique do i have to use to effectively measure performance in java?

Comment: @aarish: That really depends on what you're trying to measure. But the first thing you should do is work out what would constitute acceptable performance, and check whether or not you're already meeting that. If you are, your work is complete. (Having said that, I wouldn't use `FileWriter` anyway, as it *always* uses the default encoding... I prefer to specify that explicitly.)

Comment: Rule of thub: write correct code first (Java makes it especially "easy" to do that with all testing frameworks etc), and then make it faster only if need be. If you want a performance testing tool, have a look at [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper). Also, you are dealing with disk I/O, which means performance is really dependent on your OS/filesystem/hardware combination, _not_ your Java code

Comment: @JonSkeet: Alright thanks.. Which would you use to write to files?

Comment: I'd use `OutputStreamWriter` wrapped around a `FileOutputStream` - and quite possibly wrap that in a `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: If you use Java 7, you can use `Files.newBufferedWriter()`.

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct answer, but anyway.

**DON'T DO THAT!**

What do you think will happen if for some reason writing the new data to the file *fails*?

You not only lose your original file, but also the new file contents...

Write the new content to *another file*, ensure that it is well written and closed, *and then* rename the new file atomically to the original file.

PS: and do not forget to correctly `.close()`.

PS2: if you use Java 7, use the new [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) API.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to make a temp file and then rename the tempfile and delete the old like here:

```
    public static void nachtragenTRA(File files) throws IOException{

    Scanner sc=null;
        File f= files;
        String analyse = "";
        String NTausgabe = "";
        int max = 0;
        int k = 0;
        String updatedLine[] = new String [4];
        int filenr = 1;
        boolean sucess = false;

        try{
            sc= new Scanner(f);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException x){
            System.out.println("Error: File not found!");
        }
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){                                       //get next line

            analyse = sc.nextLine();

            max = analyse.length();                             //get line lenght

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(analyse);        //write analyse in StringBuffer 
                                                                //to change the string

            if(k == 1)
            {
                sb.replace(Daten.NTdatapos[3],max, Daten.NTProbentypTextfield.getText());
                updatedLine[0] =String.valueOf(sb);
            }
            else if(k == 2)
            {
                sb.replace(Daten.NTdatapos[4],max, Daten.NTPrueferTextfield.getText());
                updatedLine[1] =String.valueOf(sb);
            }
            else if(k == 3)
            {
                sb.replace(Daten.NTdatapos[5],max, Daten.NTKundeTextfield.getText());
                updatedLine[2] =String.valueOf(sb);
            }
            else if(k == 4)
            {
                sb.replace(Daten.NTdatapos[5],max, Daten.NTWerkstoffTextfield.getText());
                updatedLine[3] =String.valueOf(sb);
            }   

            if(k>3)
            {
                break;
            }

            k++;
        }
        sc.close();


        //NTausgabe=DatenTextarea.getText()+"\n"+updatedLine[0]+"\n"+updatedLine[1];
        //DatenTextarea.setText(String.valueOf(NTausgabe));

        //NTausgabe=DatenTextarea.getText()+"\n"+NTKundeTextfield.getText()+"\n"+NTPrueferTextfield.getText();
        //DatenTextarea.setText(String.valueOf(NTausgabe));


        //create tmp file with the new data
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(String.valueOf(f)+".tmp")));
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new FileReader(String.valueOf(f));
            br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    //Change speciffic lines
                    if(filenr == 2)
                    {
                        writer.println(updatedLine[0]);
                    }
                    else if(filenr == 3)
                    {
                        writer.println(updatedLine[1]);
                    }
                    else if(filenr == 4)
                    {
                        writer.println(updatedLine[2]);
                    }
                    else if(filenr == 5)
                    {
                        writer.println(updatedLine[3]);
                    }
                    //Andere Zeilen beibehalten
                    else
                    {   
                        writer.println(line);
                    }

                filenr = filenr + 1;
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                reader.close();
                br.close();

                File realName = new File(String.valueOf(f));
                realName.delete();                                              //delete old file
                writer.close();
                sucess = new File(String.valueOf(f)+".tmp").renameTo(realName); //rename tmp File to the others name
                if(sucess != true)
                {
                    NTausgabe=Daten.DatenTextarea.getText()+"\n"+"Rename File failed";
                    Daten.DatenTextarea.setText(String.valueOf(NTausgabe));
                }
                else
                {
                    NTausgabe=Daten.DatenTextarea.getText()+"\n"+"File renamed sucessfully";
                    Daten.DatenTextarea.setText(String.valueOf(NTausgabe));
                }
            }

 }
```

Comment: You forget to check the result of `.delete()` and `.rename()`. Also, if you use Java 7, use the new `Files` API...

Comment: So jet i really know that i write bad code :D. If you will see the complete code of my projetct i think you would selfkill you.